# About Inductive-Contextual method

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, teaching-methods, direct-method

I am currently reading Lingva Latina per se illustrata, by Oerberg. It follows the [Inductive-Contextual method](http://wikigyan1.blogspot.com/2011/08/inductive-contextual-method.html), which I find quite pleasant and effective. I have not found, however, books using this method to teach other languages, which strikes me as weird. Thus my question: Do you know of more books implementing this method?

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange! This is an interesting question but I'm afraid it has been asked before ... (although the term "natural approach" was used rather than "inductive-contextual method".)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  although I fail to see how does that post adress my question. I've asked about books implementing the direct method in other languages (other than Latin), but they don't talk about that in that other question.

Comment: You're right, I pointed to the wrong question and I have corrected this now. Can you have another look?

Comment: Checked, okey, thanks :)